# how to enable start/stop/restart for a newly added service in Ubuntu

Tags: services, init

I have created a service which does some database connection and does some query.
I want to know if I want to enable "service xyzservice start" or "service xyzservice stop" or restart where Do i need to make this service entry in Ubuntu? what are the steps.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I have created a service", I wonder if you mean "I have created a shell script" or something similar. As creating a service would involve writing a `.service` file, which is 90% of the challenge in performing the task.

So, for the sake of this answer, I'm going to assume that you've created a shell script called `query_db.sh`. The next step will be to create the `.service` file, then enable it.

Here is how you create a service:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create a new file for the service. I will call mine `query_db.service`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/query_db.service
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor you wish. The use of `vi` in this example is neither a suggestion nor an endorsement. It's just a force of habit.</sub>
2. Paste the following into the new file, editing the relevant values where appropriate:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Do Some Query

   [Service]
   User=dheeraj
   WorkingDirectory=/home/dheeraj/scripts
   ExecStart=/home/dheeraj/scripts/query_db.sh
   Type=simple
   TimeoutStopSec=10
   Restart=on-failure
   RestartSec=5

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Be sure to change the `User`, `WorkingDirectory`, and `ExecStart` values to something correct. The other items can remain untouched if you are unsure of how to configure them.</sub>
3. Verify that the script file is executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /home/dheeraj/scripts/query_db.sh
   ```
4. Reload the `systemd` daemons:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
5. Enable your daemon:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable query_db
   ```
6. Start your daemon:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start query_db
   ```

That's all there is to it. You can now check the status of your service with:

```
sudo systemctl status query_db
```

And, of course, you can stop your service with:

```
sudo systemctl stop query_db
```

If you prefer to use the shorter commands, swap the action with the service name:

```
sudo service query_db status
sudo service query_db stop
```

That's really all there is to it.

Comment: On my ssystem getting error :bash: systemctl: command not found

Comment: # cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial


I read on some sites we need to use Upstart if systemctl is not found , 
Can you help me with steps for making service able to restart/stop/start using Upstart?

Comment: Nope. Apologies, but I cannot help. 16.04 has been EOL for a few months already and I don’t have any VMs of that version to do testing with anymore.

Comment: Thanks Matigo , If you have any reference which I can use and try those things that would be helpful.
I am done with code for 3 services but not able make them enable wrt this start/stop/restart operations.